# Find Source dialog opens when starting WPF application

Tags: wpf, dll

I am trying to use a Control made by somebody else and defined in a .dll-file.
I have referenced the dll in my project and imported namespace in the XAML.
I have also set up the control in XAML. At design time I see the control ok.

When launching the app, a dialog window opens with a title "Find Source: MyView.cs"

From Object Browser, I see that this class exists under the dll.

What does this mean?

Comment: This Dialog Box is displayed when the debugger tries to display a source code file, and can determine the name of the file, but cannot determine the path of the file. I think there is a Cancel button on this Dialog Box. What happens when you click it? What happens when you run the app in Release mode?

Comment: The Source Not Found page also appears and says: You need to find MyView.cs to view the source for the current call stack frame. I can't find such source file from the dialog since all I have is the .dll.

Comment: Is this what happen when you click Cancel or when you run in Release Mode? Or both?